# How do I find out, using javascript, what software opened and running my application?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an application in HTML5 and javascript that obviously will run in any browser, but it also can be loaded into another software (other.app) that uses its' functionalities.

I need to create a condition so when my app is loaded in a browser, it will not execute the functions that are referring to other.app.

Example:

```
function doStuff(){

  if(isOtherApp){
     doOtherAppFunction();
  }

  doAllOtherStuff();
}
```

Is there a way in javascript to find out what application loaded and is execution my application?

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't use `[code]` tags (or *any* BBCode).  It uses Markdown.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a reliable way, but you can check a property provided by the JavaScript engine and test if it exists or has a certain value.

If your application is providing extra JavaScript methods and you only want to call them if they exist, then you can just test for their existence:

```
if (window.nonStandardFeature) {
    window.nonStandardFeature();
}
```